# How to aesthetically customize the numbering of formulas

Tags: equations

In my book I would like to have the numbers of my equations or this type

### (1.1-1) or [1.1-1]

I do not like the numbering of the formulas as shown in the figure:

### (1.11), (1.12), etc..

I remember that the first two digits (red rectangles) they refer to
the section and the last number refers to the progressive numbering of the formulas.

The problem is that if in a section the formulas are more than 100, I have a numeration of this type: for example for paragraph 1.2, I will have (1.2100) which is aesthetically ugly to be seen.

I kindly ask for your help to modify my code in order to have either the type of numbering with the round brackets, for example, (1.1.-1), (1.1.-2), (1.1.-3), or with square brackets [1.1.-1], [1.1.-2], [1.1.-3]. Thank you to everybody.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
 \usepackage[italian]{babel}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithin{equation}{section}


\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{Some equations}
\begin{equation}
\overline p=\frac{m \overline u}{\sqrt{1-(u/c)^2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\section{Others equations}
\begin{equation}
b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add `\newtagform{Sebastiano}{[}{]}
\usetagform{Sebastiano}` under `\begin{document}` in @Bernard's nice answer.

Comment: @marmot I have upvoted Bernard :-) and you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two solutions, with parentheses and with brackets around the equation numbers. I don't think the format with a dot+hyphen separator looks very nice, so I removed the (second) dot, but it's easy to add it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, italian]{book}
 \usepackage{babel}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}

\newtagform{bracket}{[}{]}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\section{Some equations}
\begin{equation}
\overline p=\frac{m \overline u}{\sqrt{1-(u/c)^2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\section{Others equations}
\usetagform{bracket}
\begin{equation}
b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm quite sorry – a problem with my clipboard manager. I should have checked  what was posted. Fixed now.

Comment: I have seen. Don't worry. Could you also add the code with square brackets and the image?

Comment: With square brackets, yes, in a moment, but what do you mean with the image? A red frame around the section number?

Comment: Bernard and marmot thanks to your invaluable help I would not be able to get the code that I was hoping for. I accept Bernard's answer.

Comment: I've changed the code to show both solutions on the same image.

Comment: PERFECTTTTTTTTTTT!

Comment: Do you really think perfection belongs to this world ? ;o) And as there's no other world…

Comment: My English is not very good. But for my book now I'm happy. With lot T in Sicily we tell that we are happy. :-)

Comment: Didn't know that. I know better Droopy's style (You know what? I'm happy, said with a gloomy voice)